# Retrieve numeric range output from varchar column in redshift sql

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to retrieve numeric range from varchar column, however not able to execute

The column sid_id is varchar and has numeric as well as alphanumeric values like

```
09446115979980
09446115980104
09446115981633
A1X98090900900
```

However, I am looking to extract only numeric values in particular range

Have already tried

`sid_id as bigint`:

> ERROR: XX000: Invalid digit, Value 'D', Pos 14, Type: Long

`sid_id as numeric`:

> ERROR: XX000: Invalid digit, Value 'D', Pos 14, Type: Decimal

`sid_id as varchar`: giving blank output

```
The code used is  

with tid as
(
select cast(sid_id as bigint) sid
from mf1.tb1 s                     
where 
right(sid_id,13) similar to '[0-9]{13}'
and left(sid_id,4)= '0944'
)
select tid.sid from tid
where tid.sid between 9445897133440 and 9445907133438
or tid.sid between 9446098650000 and 9446198649999
```

**FYI.. Only last 2 lines is throwing error, which is the necessity in this code**

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Updated with sample data and desired range is mentioned in last 2 lines of code

Answer (score 0):

How about just using string comparisons:

```
select s.sid
from mf1.tb1 s
where s.sid ~ '^[0-9]*$' and
      (s.sid between '09445897133440' and '09445907133438' or
       s.sid between '09446098650000' and '09446198649999'
      )
```

Interesting that this does not work with `similar to`, but it does with `~`.

This is not 100% the same as your logic, but it probably does what you want for the data you have.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=bd931c1321c42acf6533075975ad52d8) is a db<>fiddle using Postgres.

Comment: Hey Gordon thanks for the help, however this is giving NULL output

Comment: @SumitJain . . . It does not work using `similar to` but it does using `~` (in Postgres).  And it should also work in Redshift.